# ADO.net - how do I reload database data into an existing & filled DataTable?

Tags: ado.net

If I have an existing DataTable (already filled) but then I want to refresh/reload the data from the database directly (as I know there was a non-ADO.net process that changed data without going through the DataTable), however do I do this "refresh".  Note the database data at that point can overwrite whatever is in the DataTable.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [DataTable.Clear()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.clear.aspx).

Comment: Followed by a DataAdapter Fill?

Answer (score 1):

How about after clear your DataTable then fill it again.